# Validation errors appearing before submitting information in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, controller, new-operator

I have two models, Character and Initiative, and their relationship is Character has_one Initiative and Initiative belogns_to Character. I'm working on validation for Initiative, and I have it working, but the issue is all of my validation errors appear when creating a new Initiative record for a Character, before entering any information. Any ideas? Here's my code from Initiatives controller:

```
def new
  @character = Character.find(params[:character_id])
  @initiative = @character.create_initiative(params[:initiative])
end

def edit
  @character = Character.find(params[:character_id])
  @initiative = @character.initiative
end

def create
 @character = Character.find(params[:character_id])
 @initiative = @character.create_initiative(params[:initiative])
   if @initiative.save
   redirect_to character_path(@character), :notice => "initiative successfully created!"
 else
   render :action => "new"
  end
end

def update
  @character = Character.find(params[:character_id])
  @initiative = @character.initiative
    if @initiative.update_attributes(params[:initiative])
    redirect_to character_path(@character), :notice => 'Initiative information was     successfully updated.'
else
  render :action => "edit"
  end
end
```

And here's the validation itself from my model:

```
validates_presence_of :dex, :misc, :speed
validates_numericality_of :dex, :misc, :speed
```

I'm pretty sure the problem lies in the create or new methods, but I'm not sure why it's triggering the validation before a user enters any information. Any help? Maybe not a huge concern, since the code IS working, but I'd rather not display an error message before actually getting an error. Thanks!

Comment: `validate` is certainly getting called. the question is where. what's in the `new.html.erb` ? Add a `before_validate` in the model and see if that is getting called and from where. Maybe `create_initiative` in `new` is causing a validation

Comment: you're right, the `create_initiative` does call a validation. see the link in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't you be using build_initiative instead of create_initiative in your new action ? no need to save an object when sending to the user a form that intends to create it. Moreover, if your character has_one initiative, he can only have one so i doubt AR appreciates that you try to create another.

see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Having create_initiative instead of build_initiative in the new action was the culprit. I didn't quite understand the difference between the two, but the link you provided helped.